# pointer being freed was not allocated (creating dynamic copy of the class)

Tags: c++, xcode7

I need to write a program, where I have to create class with elements, where memory is allocated dynamically. When I dynamically create two instances of my class (m1 and m2) and make a copy of m1 (code: m1=m2), compiler says the next:

```
C++(11253,0x100084000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1002000b0:
pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

Here is my class:

```
class CharArray {
private:
    char *array;
public:
//Конструкторы
CharArray() {
    array=new char[1];
}
CharArray(char *str) {
    array=new char[strlen(str)];
    strcpy(array, str);
}
CharArray(const CharArray &a) {
    array=new char[strlen(a.array)];
    strcpy(array, a.array);
}

//Деструктор
~CharArray() {
    delete [] array;
    //cout << "Сработал деструктор!" << endl;
}

//Остальные методы
//Выводит на экран содержимое массива
void ShowArray();
//Ввод данных в массив
void EnterString();
//Вывод информации о массиве
void InfoAboutArray();
int SayLength();
CharArray operator+(CharArray &secondArray) const;
//CharArray& operator=(const CharArray &a);
CharArray& operator=(const char *a);
//Делаем большие буквы мальнькими и наоборот
void UpperCaseToLowerAndLowerCaseToUpper();
//Делаем маленькие буквы большие
void AllUpperCase();
//Делаем большие буквы маленькими
void AllLowerCase();

//Перегрузка операторов new и delete
void* operator new(size_t size);
void operator delete(void *p);

void* operator new[](size_t size);
void operator delete[](void *p);
};
```

Here is my main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
char m[16]="Hello, World!!!";
CharArray *m1;
cout << "Динамическое создание экземпляра класса, его инициализация строкой \"Hello, World!!!\" и вывод содержимого экземпляра на экран:" << endl;
m1=new CharArray(m);
m1->ShowArray();
cout << "Создание динамической копии экземпляра класса" << endl;
CharArray *m2;
m2=m1;
cout << "Вывод содержимого копии экземпляра на экран:" << endl;
m2->ShowArray();
delete m1;
delete m2;
return 0;
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: use a `std::vector` or `std::string`

Comment: in your constructors, you don't allocate enough: `array=new char[strlen(str)+1]` should be used instead of `array=new char[strlen(str)]` before `strcpy`.

Comment: why do you dynamically allocate objects that dynamically allocate an array in their constructor? At least your main you could keep free of `new` and `delete`

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: The number of `new` and `delete` statements should match. (2 times `new` -> 2 times `delete`, etc...)

Comment: You'd do well to read up on smart pointers, standard containers (like vector), raii and modern C++ in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in your main:

```
m2=m1;
```

since `m2` and `m1` are pointers, it will assign the address in `m1` into `m2`.

That's not wrong, but when you:

```
delete m1;
delete m2;
```

The first statement will destroy the memory, and the second statement will try to destroy the same memory (because you pointers are the same).

There is a problem with ownership: when `m1` release its ownership, the you should set it to null (`m1 = nullptr`).

That's why your code produces that error. Anyway there are other mistakes with the memory in your code (as you can see in other answers or comments).

Comment: So, and how can I create a dynamic copy of the object of my class and destroy object and its copy?

Comment: `m2 = m1` will copy pointers. `*m2 = *m1` will copy the pointed object. Note that `m2` and `m1` must to be properly initialized and you should define a proper `operator=` for you class.

Answer (score 0):

`array=new char[strlen(str)];` is wrong; you need `array=new char[strlen(str) + 1];`

Same holds for `array=new char[strlen(a.array)];`

The variables `m1` and `m2` are not of type `CharArray`; they are of type **pointer to** `CharArray`;  therefore, when you do `m2=m1`; (well, Biagio has already answered that, so I quit.)